# Outputting the correct results from a foreach loop using key identifers PHP 

Tags: php, loops, foreach, key

I have this array

```
  array(1) { [0]=> array(5)
           { ["ppc_acc_name"]=> string(9)  "Test test"      
             ["ppc_acc_username"]=> string(4) "ttes" 
             ["ppc_acc_password"]=> string(3) "tes" 
             ["ppc_acc_answer"]=> string(3) "trt"
             ["ppc_acc_link_client"]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

And I have trying to access the values in the array via a foreach loop. I want to use key string identifiers so I can control the formatting of my loop as it outputs. The problem is that it dosent let me use key string identifiers in my foreach loop.

This loop outputs Test test ttes tes trt 3 which is correct

```
  <?php foreach ($ppcAccDetails as $details): ?>

    <?php foreach ($details as $detail): ?>

        <?php echo $detail." "; ?>

    <? endforeach; ?>


<? endforeach; ?>
```

But I want to use the keys $detail['ppc_acc_name'] the results output only the first characters.

incorrect result: T t t t 3

Comment: foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)

Comment: @Waygood Dosent work I have tried that and it still comes up with the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a nested array. Just do this to access individual items:

```
echo $ppcAccDetails[0]['ppc_acc_name'];
```

In the `foreach` loop context, you would do this, and get rid of the inner `foreach` loop.

```
<?php foreach ($ppcAccDetails as $details): ?>
     <?php echo $details['ppc_acc_name']; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function in php, it should do what you want.